# Where would I ask a question about interacting with 'mailman'

Tags: support

I have a question about sending commands to a 'mailman' mailing list manager to make it do something. Would that be appropriate for this site? It's not really about computer software on my computer; on the other hand, it's not a web app (or rather, I'm not asking about the web frontend of it).

To be more specific: I want to avoid the periodic list membership reminds.

Comment: how basic/complex? Might be a SF question, but more information would be handy

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: See edit.

Comment: We already have [questions about mailman](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mailman). I'd say it's fine

Comment: Are you an end-user or are you running a mailman server?

Comment: @SimonSheehan: end-user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `mailman` is an existing tag on this site, and you are the end-user, I think it is most appropriate to belong on Super User.

If your question were to do with the back end of a mailing list, then it would belong on Server Fault.